# Looking for a free CMS which allows content injection

Tags: content-management-system, system, customization

I was wondering if anyone could tell me of a free CMS that will allow me to change the basic content (text, image etc etc) of a website, without forcing it's own templates or designs.

This is the scenario; I have already designed my website, already implemented it, and I just need a way for the actual User to edit the contents of the pages.

I've looked into Drupal and Joomla, and the hosted ones such as CushyCMS (I liked the way this worked) and SimpleCMS, however I am a bit wary of hosted CMS systems...

Any ideas??

Comment: Belongs on http://doctype.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest [MODx](http://www.modxcms.com/) - it's a [very well supported](http://modxcms.com/forums/), free, open source CMS with a great community. You are in complete control and creating templates is a simple as copying and pasting your existing HTML - just replace the content with the [*content*] template variable, and it'll be replaced by whatever the user enters in the excellent, built in manager.

Here are a couple of great tuorials that will get you started:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/working-with-a-content-management-framework-modx/ - this is an excellent overview
- http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2009/03/28/building-a-website-with-modx-for-newbies-part-1-introduction/ - this is a series taking you from installing, to a finished site.

Comment: Also, you might find this site useful:

http://php.opensourcecms.com/

it lets you see demo's of various different CMS's, has reviews, ratings, etc...

Answer (score 0):

With wordpress you can write your own templates (It's called themes there).

I think you can basically pour your own code as is and add calls to the wordpress framework whenever you need the actual content.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the best option for you (given that your site is basically ready) is to use a WYSIWYG editor. I would recommend [tinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). It will allow your users to simply create html markup with their content which you can then save to the DB of your app and display it on the content pages.